# How do you build this circuit on a breadboard?

Tags: breadboard, circuits

[image]

How do you build this circuit on a breadboard?

Comment: Why do you need to build it on a breadboard? This circuit doesn't do anything except create voltage drops. You can easily just analyze it or simulate it.

Comment: I know that I can simulate it, but I was wondering on how to apply it to a physical environment. So, I can learn how to apply it to other circuits.

Comment: You just plug the resistors into the breadboard according to the respective nets... Surely, your question is more basic: how to use a breadboard? Do you need to know how the holes are connected? There are myriad guides on the internet for your perusal.

Comment: There is a circuit tool called fritzing that will take a schematic like this and show you a breadboard version. But learning how a breadboard works is better in the long run.

Comment: _Edit your question_ to specify what you mean by "breadboard".  The original breadboard was just that -- a wooden board, made for slicing bread, that you filched from the kitchen to the aggravation of the cook, and built a circuit upon.  I don't _think_ you mean that, but one could build that circuit on a real breadboard.  Today, "breadboard" applies to _many different things_ that lead to easy circuit prototyping.

Comment: Often the first iteration was the "christmas tree" ie the components joined together in the same layout as the diagram you show using the leads of the components and often soldered together. Very fragile and easy to cause shorts etc but often a quick test for functionality. A simple example: https://www.homemade-circuits.com/how-to-make-interesting-random-led/

Answer (score 2):

- Connect your 5 V supply positive to the red strip of sockets at the edge of the board. Everything connected to N1 will plug into this strip.
- Connect the 5 V common to the blue strip of sockets at the edge of the board. Everything connected to GND will plug into this strip.
- Pick any two 5-pin strips and (mentally or physically) label these 'N2' and 'N3'. Since R1 has to have a leg in each pick two strips separated by at least the length of the resistor body.
- Add in the resistors between the appropriate strips.

This will probably look a little messy so when you're finished rip everything out and do it again trying to be a bit tidier.

[image]

*Figure 1. A nice tidy example of what's possible from [How to use a breadboard](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-a-breadboard/).*

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear?  Do you have some perf-board?  Have you used it before?  do you have a solderless proto-board?

Building that exact circuit will take a little extra effort, because of the five resistors shown, only two of them are standard E-24 or E-96 values.  You can use two 18K resistors in parallel for R4, two 12K resistors in parallel for R1, and two 2K resistors in series for R3.

Comment: Sorry, the values were not so important. We can imagine, that they are all of 1 kohm. How would it then look like? I am using a digilent solderless breadboard, and I am new to this.

Comment: Maybe a video tutorial could help more than typed words: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WReFkfrUIk

Comment: I understand how a breadboard is connected, but I just wasn't able to visualize this specific circuit on a breaboard.

Comment: @user1074981 ignore r1. Can you visualize the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just plug in one component at a time.

Let's say you start with R2. Just plug it into any two rows. Now those rows are N1 and N2 (as labelled in the diagram). Since resistors are symmetrical, it doesn't matter which one you say is N1 and which one you say is N2.

Now say you plug in R1. You plug it into N2 (pick one of the rows where R2 is plugged in) and N3 (any new row of your choice).

Now do, for example, R5. Plug it into N1 and N3. Now R3 - pick a row to be ground, and plug it between N2 and ground. And so on for R4. And plug the power supply between N1 and ground.

Most breadboards have special power rows that go all the way across the breadboard. Because they go sideways along the board, you can easily plug between these ones and any other rows. I would recommend using the +/red rail for N1 and the -/black rail for ground, and then you don't need to remember those two. A warning: Sometimes they only go halfway across the breadboard and the coloured lines are drawn to show this.

Comment: Sometimes the colored lines have a break, but the connectivity is continuous. No, I don't get it either, but I've encountered enough cases of this to know that you can't rely on the lines to tell you if there's continuity or not.